# Array Struct in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

When calling the procedure below with input as array of struct, I am getting an error. Code has compiled fine but I'm getting error while calling.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Test4`(IN v_name_struct ARRAY<struct<roll numeric,dept string>>, OUT id ARRAY<STRING>)
begin 

for i in (select x.roll,x.dept from unnest(v_name_struct)as x)
do
update `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Employee` 
set salary='1000'
where roll=i.roll;
end for;

end;

DECLARE v_name_struct ARRAY<STRUCT<roll NUMERIC, dept STRING>> DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE id ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT NULL;
CALL `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Test4`([(2,'ECE')], id);--Getting error in this
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `OUT id ARRAY<STRING>` ? you are not setting the output variable in the procedure. `id` variable should come from where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the comment about the output of your procedure. I think I will do the following to address your issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `projectid.dataset.proc_test4`(IN v_name_struct ARRAY<struct<roll numeric,dept string>>, OUT id ARRAY<STRING>)
begin 

for i in (select x.roll,x.dept from unnest(v_name_struct)as x)
do

    update `projectid.dataset.Employee_test4`
    set salary='1000'
    where roll=i.roll;

end for;

set id = (select [dept] from `projectid.dataset.Employee_test4` where salary="1000");

end;
```

As you can see below, you have to pass the variables you are setting in your procedure. In this case, if you do not pass `numeric` type you will get errors. You can use `cast` to convert the value to `numeric`.

```
DECLARE v_name_struct ARRAY<STRUCT<roll NUMERIC, dept STRING>> DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE id ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT NULL;

set v_name_struct = [(cast(2 as numeric),'ECE')];
CALL `projectid.dataset.proc_test4`(v_name_struct, id);
select id;
```

For additional information about cast you can check following link:

- [Conversion Rules](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules)
- [Conversion Functions - CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions)

Comment: Hello @TBose, have you managed to make it work?